# Is there any way to have a Case workflow rule create a task with WhatID set as the triggering Case's AccountID?

Tags: workflow, case, tasks, action

I have a workflow rule on the Case object that is supposed to create a task, but I want to associate the task with the Account that the Case belongs to, not to the Case itself.  I have seen that I can't use an Account Task creation workflow action on a Case workflow rule, but does anyone know of a workaround?

(PS I know I could just write it up in an Apex trigger, but I want to handle it in Workflow if possible)

Comment: did you try using processBuilder to update a field on Cases's parent Account that in turn does a workflow/process step that creates the Task?

Comment: Holy moly, I never used processBuilder before!  I was able to do it without an intermediary field change, just by creating a task with RelatedToID set as the Case's Account ID.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Go ahead and post your solution after the requisite 1 day delay

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the tip from crop1645, I checked out the new proccessBuilder feature, where I was able to do exactly what I wanted to in a single action.

ProcessBuilder is a more flexible tool than regular Workflow Rules, and I may even take some processes that I previously could only implement in Apex and move them over to processBuilder.